# Codeception - click simple link

Tags: xpath, codeception

How can I click on a simple link `<a href="/some_page.html">Some page</a>` via Codeception `AcceptanceTester` man?

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - WebDriver
      - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
      WebDriver:
          url: 'http://mysite.local'
          browser: 'firefox'
          windowSize: '1024x768'
```

I'm trying:

```
public function somePage(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage('/');
    $I->click('Some page', '//a[href="/some_page.html"]');
}
```

but getting next message:

```
...
CSS or XPath element with '//a[href="/some_page.html"]' was not found.
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong xpath, it should be:

`$I->click('Some page','//a[@href="/some_page.html"]');`

So you are missing @ in front of href.

Just to mention if you have more links of this kind than you could access first one with this:

```
$I->click('Some page','(//a[@href="/some_page.html"])[1]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this HTML structure:

```
<section id="products-anchor" class="products-list">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="products">
            ***
            <li class="">
                <h3>
                    <a href="/some_page.html"> Some page </a>
                </h3>
                <p>
                    <a href="/some_page.html"></a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="/some_page.html">Text for some page...</a>
                </p>
                <p></p>
            </li>
            ***
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply user Locator class here. Please check below snippet. I have used the same but using functional call. Consider that I am passing that element contains URL from my cept file.

> use \Codeception\Util\Locator; Class ClassName{
>
> public function fun_name( $strSomeVar, $selectorUrl ){
>
> ```
>     $I->see( $strSomeVar, Locator::href( $selectorUrl ) );
>     $I->click( Locator::href( $selectorUrl ) );
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

May be this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have to indicate the `h3`, but I'm pretty sure this will work.

```
$I->click(['xpath'=> '//ul/li/h3/a[@href="/some_page.html"]']);
```